# Is it possible to check equality of equi-recursive types, or recursive λ-terms?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

### Can we determine if two λ-terms are equal?

Given two lambda terms, let's say they are equal if their (possibly infinite) Bohm trees are. Under this definition, for example, `(Y λr.λt.(t r))` and `(Y λr.λt.(t (λt. (t r))))` are equal, despite not having a normal form, because both terms have the same infinite Bohm trees. I believe this problem, in general, is undecidable. Is there any efficient, preferably simple algorithm capable of determining if two λ-terms are equal for some large class of common terms? The main problem, I believe, is finding the right series of reductions that make two terms identical without getting stuck in an infinite loop.

### Can we determine if two equi-recursive types are equal?

Suppose we extend CoC with equi-recursive types. Naturally, type checking the application of a `f : ∀ (x : A) -> B` to a `x : A'` requires you to check if `A == A'`. In plain CoC, this can be done by merely reducing both sides to normal form and checking if they are equal. In the presence of equi-recursive types, though, that isn't possible. Is there any algorithm capable of checking if two types are equal in such language?

---

Note: I'm not sure if those questions are equivalent and I felt that asking another question would be spammy, so I've asked both in this same thread.

Comment: You might want to check this answer of mine: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/41176/3984 short answer: equi-recursive type equivalence is decidable for simple types. The general problem you posed is highly undecidable, since it isn't even decidable whether a term has a head normal form.