# Definitional equality of recursive function definition by "infinite unfolding"

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, recursion

The context is checking definitional equality in dependent type theory implementations.

Consider in Coq

```
Fixpoint predd(a: nat): nat := 
  match a with
  | O => O
  | S b => predd(b)
  end.

Fixpoint preddd(a: nat): nat := 
  match a with
  | O => O
  | S b => match b with | O => O | S c => preddd(c) end
  end.


Fixpoint predd2(a: nat): nat := 
  match a with
  | O => O
  | S b => preddd(b)
  end.
```

So `predd` is a function that recursively call itself and return `O` eventually. it is popositionaly equal to `_ => O`

`preddd` is the `predd` unfold once inside.

`predd2` is just `predd` but calls `preddd` inside.

`predd2` and `preddd` is not definitionaly equal in Coq. But can we have another definitional equality for recursive functions?

I have an idea of definitional equality of recursive functions, such that if the infinite unfolding of recursive definition is equal, then the two value is equal. such "infinite unfolding" seems can be made precise by requiring the finite unfoldings of values always have a *similarity relation*.

So, is there a sound definition of "definitional equality of recursive functions by infinite expansions"?

Can this be constructively implemented?

Comment: Why is `predd` is propositionally equal to `fun _ => 0`? (Try proving it.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer sorry I means assuming function extensionality

Comment: @AndrejBauer also see my comment below https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/definitional-equality-of-recursive-function-definition-by-infinite-unfolding/42379#comment98423_42379 for some clearance....

Comment: Do you expect "definitional equality" to be checked by an algorithm? Is that what you mean when you say "constructively implemented"? What would it mean to implement "non-constructively"?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I am using "definitional equality" and judgmental equality" as the same thing now, so maybe I should say judgemental equality, but yes, I expect it be checked with an algorithm

Comment: Checking equality of infinte trees can be problematic (which is what your unfoldings are). If you know something extra about the trees (for instance, if they're [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_tree_grammar)) then there might be an algorithm. In the present case, after you've figured out what you mean by "infinite unfolding", it looks like you don't stand a chance. The trees will be very complex.

Answer (score 2):

Your `predd2` is not a fixpoint; you could replace the `Fixpoint` by `Definition`. And the fact that they are not convertible is due to the lack of eta-conversion for inductive types in Coq.

The reason for this is that we want the conversion to be decidable, and it's already hard to decide beta-eta-conversion in the simply typed case (see Deciding equivalence with sums and the empty type by Gabriel Scherer).

---

You can more or less check that "`a` is convertible to `b`" by using the following notation:

```
Notation "n ~ m" := (eq_refl : n = m) (at level 70, no associativity).
```

(It has the expected behaviour on `+`:

```
Check fun n => 0 + n ~ n.
Fail Check fun n => n + 0 ~ n.
```

)

And you can check that there is no eta-conversion for booleans, for natural numbers, or even for the unit type:

```
Fail Check fun x : bool => if x then tt else tt ~ tt.
Fail Check fun x : nat => match x with | 0 => tt | S _ => tt end ~ tt.
Fail Check fun x : unit => match x with tt => tt end ~ tt.
```

(Those are specific cases of the eta conversion for those inductive types, but since they already fail, it still shows that the full eta conversion can't be included in the conversion)

Now, going back to your specific example (with the names changed). I use the names:

- $f_i$ for the recursive function that returns $0$ immediately if its argument $n$ is between $0$ and $i-1$, and otherwise recursively calls its self on $n-i$. $f_1$ is your `predd` and $f_2$ is your `preddd`.
- $\text{eta}\_\text{fun}\_f_i$ is the eta-expansion (as a function) of $f_i$.
- $\text{eta}\_\text{fun}\_\text{eta}\_\text{nat}\_f_i$ is the result of eta-expanding the body (with the eta-expansion of natural numbers) of $\text{eta}\_\text{fun}\_f_i$.
- $g_i$ is the function that returns $0$ immediately if its argument $n$ is $0$, and otherwise returns $f_i(n-1)$.

We have $g_1\equiv \text{eta}\_f_1 \not \equiv \text{eta}\_\text{fun}\_\text{eta}\_\text{nat}\_f_2 \equiv f_1$, which shows that the problem is indeed the lack of eta-conversion for natural numbers.

We have $g_1\equiv \text{eta}\_f_1 \not \equiv \text{eta}\_\text{fun}\_\text{eta}\_\text{nat}\_f_2 \not\equiv f_1$. The first $\not\equiv$ is still due to the same reason. I think the second one is more about unfolding of fixpoints.

Here is a Coq script that supports what I said above:

```
Fixpoint f1 n := (* predd *)
  match n with
  | O => O
  | S n' => f1 n'
  end
.

Definition eta_fun_f1 n :=
  f1 n
.

Definition eta_fun_eta_nat_f1 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => f1 0
  | S n' => f1 (S n')
  end
.

Definition g1 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | S n' => f1 n'
  end
.

Check f1 ~ eta_fun_f1.
Fail Check eta_fun_f1 ~ eta_fun_eta_nat_f1.
Check eta_fun_eta_nat_f1 ~ g1.

Fixpoint f2 n := (* preddd *)
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | S n' =>
    match n' with
    | 0 => 0
    | S n'' => f2 n''
    end
  end
.

Definition eta_fun_f2 n :=
  f2 n
.

Definition eta_fun_eta_nat_f2 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => f2 0
  | S n' => f2 (S n')
  end
.

Definition g2 n := (* predd2 *)
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | S n' => f2 n'
  end
.

Check f2 ~ eta_fun_f2.
Fail Check eta_fun_f2 ~ eta_fun_eta_nat_f2.
Fail Check eta_fun_eta_nat_f2 ~ g2.
```

Comment: Sorry it is kind of misleading mentioning `_ => O` which has nothing to do with the question. the question is if `preddd` and `predd2` can be made definitionally equal by changing how definationaly equal is defined. it is actually quite like this question https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42333/is-it-possible-to-check-equality-of-equi-recursive-types-or-recursive-%CE%BB-terms?rq=1 but I am lacking the background to fomulate the question that way initially. also the question aforementioned is in the context of untyped lambda calculus, which is not strongly normalizing

Comment: @molikto I edited. Is it clearer?